# Detect current user facebook user

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have an android app that uses facebook SDK.

I have a problem with this scenario:

I use the my app for the first time then I log in my facebook account in my app. The credentials are then save in the app so that users will not be ask to log in again. Now, in the facebook app, I log out my account then log in again with a different user. When I go back to my app and retrieve the some user info, it still has the old user in it.

I tried to check it using `Profile.getcurrentProfile()` but it still contains info on the old user.

Is there any way to detect who's currently using the facebook app?

Comment: You are saving the credentials of old user in your app, but not changing it once you log in as new user.

Comment: @AshwiniKutre Right, but how do change it?

Comment: If you are logging out from your external facebook application, then it is not possible. But if you are logging out from your app, you can change the preference values.